# Does BeautifulSoup understand relative URLs?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape a site that uses a ton of relative URLs. One archive page has links to many individual entries, but the URL is given like "../2011/category/example.html"

For each entry, I want to open the page and scrape it, but I'm not sure what the most efficient way to handle that is. I'm thinking of splitting the starting URL by "/", pop off the last item and re-joining them, to get the base URL.

That seems like such a cludge, though. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To construct an absolute URL from a relative URL, use `urlparse.urljoin` ([docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin)).

If you are using a browsing system like `mechanize` for crawling, however, you can simply fetch an absolute url initially and then feed the browser relative urls after that.  The browser will keep track of state and fetch the URL from the same domain as the previous request automatically.

Comment: Perfect! It sounds like I should take a look at mechanize, too.